# Read the text inside li tag which is inside a class

Tags: html, jquery

I have the HTML code below and I need to read the text **Good** which is inside a **li** tag when a **click** event occurs using **jquery**. I have clicked the second **div** and I need to read the text between its li tag, i.e; **Good**. There are 22 divs with the same class name and I don't like to add **id** to all 22 divs. Now, how can I do that using jquery?

> HTML

```
<div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Hello</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">World</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Good</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Morning</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried doing this but couldn't access the **li** element. Below is my jquery code

> JQUERY

```
$(".card").click(function(e){
  console.log($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of your `.card` css selector, target only the `<li>` inside the `.card`, then use `this.text()` to get the content of the `<li>`:

**Css selector**: `.card li`

```js
$(".card li").click(function(e){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Hello</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">World</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Good</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Morning</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer but, for my application, when a user clicks on the card, I only need to read the text in between first li belonging to the clicked div. As per your code if a user clicks on the second li of any div, I'll be reading the text in between second li which I shouldn't be doing. Isn't there any other way of doing that?